# How to get page mentions appearing in www.facebook.com/pageid/posts_to_page/?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get visitors posts from API?

Visitor Posts on facebook consists of wall_posts and "... was mentioned in a post."

Some time ago (at least I think so) I could get wall posts and mentions  from /{page-id}/feed API endpoint. Wall posts are there, but mentions are not anymore.

mentions can be retrieved from /{page-id}/tagged, but there are MUCH more posts than appear in facebook.com/{page-id}/posts_to_page/. 
How to tell them apart?

in API docs developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed it says "When you use /{page-id}/tagged to show the posts that tag this page, the results include posts from other pages only if those pages are authentic." I assume that authentic pages are those who are verified public pages with blue sign near their names. But in /{page-id}/tagged i can see posts from personal blogs and random people sharing other pages posts with mentions...

same question was asked in developers.facebook.com/bugs/1863287243911547/ by another person, but answer to another question given and bug rejected.

facebook FAQ has this:

> Why do some User's posts on a Page's timeline not show up in the Graph
>   API? 
>   User's posts shared on page's timeline won't be available via the
>   API if user has base permission off for the content type of the post.
>
> As a workaround to see the missing photo posts from fans you may be
>   able to fetch the page's albums using the page access token - the
>   photos should be in the Timeline Photos album

i tried to look for mentions in Timeline Photos album, but without success

Comment: _“How to tell them apart?”_ - check the `message_tags` field, as suggested in the bug report?

Answer (score 0):

its available in latest version of graph API. [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/visitor_posts/).

```
/v2.11/{page-id}/visitor_posts
```

> Shows all public posts published by page visitors on the page

in an earlier version(2.5), I'm getting visitors post when i'm calling `/{page-id}/tagged`. I think now they changed.